# What is this 'Multiple-step OLE DB' error?

Tags: asp-classic, oledb, ado

I'm doing a little bit of work on a horrid piece of software built by Bangalores best.

It's written in mostly classic ASP/VbScript, but "ported" to ASP.NET, though most of the code is classic ASP style in the ASPX pages :(

I'm getting this message when it tries to connect to my local database:

**Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.**

```
Line 38:    MasterConn = New ADODB.Connection()
Line 39:    MasterConn.connectiontimeout = 10000
Line 40:        MasterConn.Open(strDB)
```

Anybody have a clue what this error means? Its connecting to my local machine (running SQLEXPRESS) using this connection string:

```
PROVIDER=MSDASQL;DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=JONATHAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS\;DATABASE=NetTraining;Integrated Security=true
```

Which is the connection string that it was initially using, I just repointed it at my database.

**UPDATE:**

The issue was using "Integrated Security" with ADO. I changed to using a user account and it connected just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this a long time ago with working in ASP.  I found this knowledge base article and it helped me out.  I hope it solves your problem.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269495

If this doesn't work and everything checks out, then it is probably your connection string.  I would try these steps next:

Remove:

```
DRIVER={SQL Server};
```

Edit the Provider to this:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;
```

Comment: i encountered the error because of a connection string. i had to remove Integrated Security=false;

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com) is a great site so you don't have to remember all that connection string syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem when trying to connect to an MySQL database via the wonderful Classic ASP. The solutions above didn't fix it directly, but I resolved it in the end by updating the ODBC Driver (from the long standing 3.51) to the latest version. I was then able to leave the driver line in (and not add the Provider bit), but I did have to update   the connection string accordingly to:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};
```

That worked fine. Happy chappy.