# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors

Tags: c#, oledb, netezza

I am running a simple FillSchema from a Netezza data source

```
dss = new DataSet();
ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
ad.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + objTable.name);
ad.SelectCommand.Connection = cn;
ad.FillSchema(dss, SchemaType.Source);
```

I get the following error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen(IDbConnection connection, ConnectionState& originalState)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillSchemaInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, SchemaType schemaType, IDbCommand command, String srcTable, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillSchema(DataSet dataSet, SchemaType schemaType, IDbCommand command, String srcTable, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillSchema(DataSet dataSet, SchemaType schemaType)
   at IMS.DF2.IMSCubeGenerator.IMSCube.AddTableToDatasourceView(table objTable) in C:\DIUP\DF2\IMSCubeGenerator\IMSCube.cs:line 902
```

What am I doing wrong here?

How can I get to the errors underneath (Check each OLE DB status value)?

Answer (score 3):

What's your connection string?

It will be either your Driver, your Cursor or security (I had the same problem using Integrated Security).

Changing this to a username/password fixed my issue.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730/what-is-this-multiple-step-ole-db-error), [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269495) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272730/vb6-adodb-fails-with-sql-compact-multipe-step-operation-generated-errors) for more info.

Comment: I was not aware that Netezza had Integrated Security. At any rate, I was given a Netezza login to use.

It could have been the cursor or the Driver.